# Selenium with Java: I can't find and element and click it

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

This is the button of the page I need to click:

```
<div _ngcontent-jnk-c107="" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/opportunity/1">VIEW</div>
```

I can't use the text **view** in the locator as there are other 22 buttons in the same page with the same text.

The only difference between them is that router link, which I don't know how to call. I already tried with Link text and partial link text, with no results.

Comment: Did you try css `div:[ng-reflect-router-link='/opportunity/1']` ?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:[ng-reflect-router-link='/opportunity/1']")).click();
I tried this line and it says "invalid selector"

Comment: Sorry, please remove colon `:`, `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[ng-reflect-router-link='/opportunity/1']"))`

Answer (score 0):

In case `ng-reflect-router-link` attribute value is unique for this element you can use the following XPath locator:

```
//div[@ng-reflect-router-link='/opportunity/1']
```

Comment: I tried driver.findElement(By.xpath("div[@ng-reflect-router-link='/opportunity/1']")).click();
and it still says "unable to find element"

Comment: Maybe you are missing a wait / delay before this command? Try putting something like `Thread.sleep(5000);` before it and see if it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as ***VIEW*** with respect to the *`ng-reflect-router-link`* attribute you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.btn.btn-primary.btn-outline[ng-reflect-router-link='/opportunity/1']")).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='btn btn-primary btn-outline' and @ng-reflect-router-link='/opportunity/1']")).click();
  ```

---

However, as the element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.btn.btn-primary.btn-outline[ng-reflect-router-link='/opportunity/1']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='btn btn-primary btn-outline' and @ng-reflect-router-link='/opportunity/1']"))).click();
  ```